# Apache URI Mappings Without Trailing Slashes But Similar Paths

Tags: apache

So I support multiple applications using an Apache frontend that largely just directs traffic to different apps. The issue I am coming across is I will have app owners tell me that want to map /abc to a particular app, but then want to map /abcd to a different app. At first, my solution was to change /abc to /abc/, but that is causing them issues that they don't want to change.

My question is, what happens when you have 2 Apache mappings that are the same, except one has extra characters at the end? Does it become a matter of order? How do I ensure which one goes where?

Example:

```
<Location /abc>
  ProxyPass /abc https://someserver-1/abc
  ProxyPassReverse /abc https://someserver-1/abc
</Location>

<Location /abcd>
  ProxyPass /abcd https://someserver-2/abcd
  ProxyPassReverse /abcd https://someserver-2/abcd
</Location>
```

Thank you in advance for any help on this!